# C# Setting maximum width of the table from datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I want to modify the width of the table inside of the datagridview. But I am lacking of resources and time to find its properties. As you can see in the picture, there is a space between the table width and the datagridview width which is unfittable. Anyone can help me? I will appreciate!

[The picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTUvR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the datagridview properties, click ColumnHeaderDefaultCellStyle.
You can edit the right padding in layout section to adjust the width of the table as fit as the datagridview width.

As you can see in the picture below.

[image: Adjust Table Padding]

Or you can set it programmatically like this code for example.

```
dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Padding = new Padding(0, 0, 30, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

select the right-hand side edit button and select all the row auto side mode to fill

picture  :
https://ibb.co/kmvcJVv

Comment: Where is exactly is the right-hand side edit button?